# Count folders and subfolders in Sharedmailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

i Would like to know if i can count folders and subfolders in sharedmailbox ;

Here is some code that im using , but it works only for my default mail account.
is there a way to modify it to get the number of subfolders in the folder "Test" from my shared mailbox name's (AJ47 BOX)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim outapp As Outlook.Application
Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNs = outapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder


TextBox1 = GetSubFolderCount(olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Tmp"))


End Sub

Private Function GetSubFolderCount(objParentFolder As MAPIFolder) As Long

Dim currentFolders As Folders
Dim fldCurrent As MAPIFolder

Set currentFolders = objParentFolder.Folders
If currentFolders.Count > 0 Then
   Set fldCurrent = currentFolders.GetFirst
   While Not fldCurrent Is Nothing
      TempFolderCount = TempFolderCount + GetSubFolderCount(fldCurrent)
      Set fldCurrent = currentFolders.GetNext
   Wend
   GetSubFolderCount = TempFolderCount + currentFolders.Count
Else
    GetSubFolderCount = 0
End If



End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GetSharedDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220116(v=office.11).aspx)

Example

```
Dim olRecip As Recipient
Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("om3r@email.com")  '// Owner's Name or email address

TextBox1 = GetSubFolderCount(olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox).Folders("Test"))
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly , i need to know something , if i would like to get only the subfolders of any subfolder , i do the same process ?

Comment: cause now it works only if i enter the name of the main folder , i tried to enter the name of the subfolder  i got this error ("Object doesnt support this property or method")

`TextBox2 = GetSubFolderCount(olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox).Folders("ACTINGS"))`

Actings is situated in 'Acting items' in tasks in Inbox  

"Inbox/taks/acting items/actings" 
thanks @Om3r

Comment: @RiadhSaïd little confused - :(?  If the Folder is the SubFolder of `"Test"` then try `(olRecip, olFolderInbox).Folders("Test").Folders("ACTINGS"))` if your working with task Folder then you will need to replace `olFolderInbox with olFolderTasks`

Comment: See [GetDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220100(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Om3r it works fine , i was just a little bit confused while trying to get the number of the subfolders under a  subfolder.

Thank you for your time :) much appreciated 


@Om3r